# Python Code Optimisation for list of dict

Tags: python

Could someone suggest some ways to Optimise the below code?

First Method

```
board =[
{"Pakistan": 123},
{"Pakistan": 27},
{"India": 3},
{"India": 71},
{"Australia": 31},
{"India": 22},
{"Pakistan": 81},
{"India": 171},
{"India": 171},
]

country = {} 
for item in board:
    for team,value in item.items():
        try: country[team].append(value)
        except KeyError: country[team] = [value]
print(country)

avg={}
for key, value in country.iteritems():
    avg[key]= sum(value)/len(value)

print(avg)

def maximum(team):
    d3={v:k for k,v in team.items()}
    return d3[max(d3)]

print(maximum(avg))
```

Second Method

```
avgDict = {}
for k,v in [(key,d[key]) for d in board for key in d]:
    if k not in avgDict: avgDict[k]=[v]
    else: avgDict[k].append(v)
print(avgDict)
```

Just to get the name and list of scores.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize"?

Comment: Write it in Cython?

Comment: You could use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension in the second method, no need to create the list.

Comment: you can use pandas, but as Guybrush says, it all depends on what you mean by _optimize_

Comment: You can also use pandas...https://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: Optimisation with respect to less loops and condition.

Answer (score 0):

here is partial solution for cleaner countries and average:

```
import numpy as np

keys = [k for d in board for k in d.keys()]
values = [v for d in board for k,v in d.items()]
avg = int(np.mean(values))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` combined with dictionary / list comprehensions. In general, these methods should be more efficient.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in board:
    for k, v in i.items():
        d[k].append(v)

d_avg = {k: sum(v)/len(v) for k, v in d.items()}

max_country = [k for k in d_avg if d_avg[k] == max(d_avg.values())]
```

**Result**

```
print(d)

defaultdict(list,
            {'Australia': [31],
             'India': [3, 71, 22, 171, 171],
             'Pakistan': [123, 27, 81]})

print(d_avg)

{'Australia': 31.0, 'India': 87.6, 'Pakistan': 77.0}

print(max_country)

['India']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using pandas could be more efficient

```
import pandas as pd

items = ((k,v) for d in board for k,v in d.items())
df = pd.DataFrame(items)
df.groupby(0).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
boardf = pd.DataFrame(board)
finaldict = {}
for country, values in boardf.items():
    finaldict[country] = values.dropna().values.tolist()
print(finaldict)
print(boardf.mean().to_dict())
print(boardf.max().sort(inplace=False, ascending=False).index[0])
```

The output is:

```
{'Australia': [31.0], 'Pakistan': [123.0, 27.0, 81.0], 'India': [3.0, 71.0, 22.0, 171.0, 171.0]}
{'Australia': 31.0, 'Pakistan': 77.0, 'India': 87.599999999999994}
India
```